# Why did youtube api for Channels statistics stopped responding correctly?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Today the GET request (https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=status&id=CHANNEL_ID&key=KEY)  returned this value:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

But before that it always returned the following:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

What can be the cause of the problem of missing attributes in the response?

Comment: If you are having an issue with the api you may want to check the issue forum https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B  I find it strange if it was returning the type as the value previously though.  (string, integer, resource ... )

Comment: Please post the culprit channel ID.

Comment: @stvar that is the problematic channel id -  UCVU0Ml1l_Y90wmy5EjWTSng

Comment: @Евгений М: I confirm the output you obtained above: the JSON response text does not include an `items` array at all, yet [the channel does exist](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVU0Ml1l_Y90wmy5EjWTSng). Thus I recommend to address this issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @ЕвгенийМ  that's a google's bug, now has been recovered ! You can try it

Comment: @Евгений М: I confirm that as of the time of this writing, this API bug has been fixed by Google; now invoking `Channels.list` on `UCVU0Ml1l_Y90wmy5EjWTSng` works as expected: got an `items` array containing one entry with expected metadata.

Answer (score -2):

Mabye the API project that "owns" the API key you are using doesn't have the YouTube Data v3 API hasn't been activated for use with the project.
And you could Try to have another API and try it with the same script then
U it could help to know what is wrong